# numberFormatException compile error

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I have been working on this for hours, and I have looked all over this site to see if maybe someone else had something similar and I cannot find anything that will help. This program will run and convert a hex number to a decimal number, and from what I can tell the exceptions are working. However, I have a compile error on lines 34 and 35, the if statements with the exceptions (these two lines are what the instructor told me to fill in and I have more than triple checked to see if it was exactly how she had it written) I can see that the error is with a parentheses, but no matter how or where I move them or remove them I cannot get the error to go away. This is what I have so far.

```
/* This program converts a hex number to a decimal number with exceptions
included.
  @author Sarah
date: 9/17/2015
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumberFormatException12_6 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner

    //prompt the user to enter a hex string
    System.out.println("Enter a hex number: ");
    //get hex string
    String hex = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("The decimal value for hex number " + hex + " is: "
    + hexToDecimal(hex.toUpperCase()));
  }
  public static int hexToDecimal(String hex) {
      int decimalValue = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
          char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);
          try {
          decimalValue = decimalValue * 16 + hexCharToDecimal(hexChar);
      }
          catch (Exception ex) {
                 System.out.println("Not a valid hex number");
                 System.exit(0);
              }
      }
      return decimalValue;
  }
  public static int hexCharToDecimal(char ch) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException {
      if((ch >='G' ||(ch < '0') throw new NumberFormatException("Not a valid hex number!");
      if((ch>=':'&& (ch<='@')throw new NumberFormatException("Not a valid hex number!");
      if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F'){
          return 10 + ch - 'A';
      }
      else {//ch is '0', '1',...or'9'
          return ch - '0';
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your missing a closing ) at the end of the second if statement.

Comment: Both if statements. Triple checked? Really?

Comment: Yes, really. This is my fourth week in my Java course. I posted what she told me I needed to add, and It was incorrect. I can screen share what she had if that is really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your parentheses.

It should be :

```
  if((ch >='G') ||(ch < '0')) throw new NumberFormatException("Not a valid hex number!");
  if((ch>=':') && (ch<='@')) throw new NumberFormatException("Not a valid hex number!");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I thought I had tried that, but apparently I didn't. I think I tried to add an extra one after the '0' but I forgot it after the 'G'...either way, you are my hero!